# Will use 'k_BackingField' cause version compatibility problem?

Tags: c#, serialization, properties, field, automatic-properties

Recently, I'm working on serialization with C#.

I found that the automatic-properties' fields are named `"<...>k_BackingField"`.

So my problem is dose this naming rule same in all .Net versions, and it won't change in any situations?

Comment: which serialization process are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an *internal* implementation that *may* change between the different versions of the C# compiler.

The different serialization mechanisms provided by the libraries have different compatibility rules. For instance, I do not believe that binary serialization is guaranteed to work between different versions of the framework.